# Suse11 - How to install pdo_mysql

Tags: pdo

I am going to install Drupal 7 to my new server, I have installed all stuff that mentioned in the requirement, however I stall get the error message saying that

"...Your web server does not appear to support any common PDO database extensions. Check with your hosting provider to see if they support PDO (PHP Data Objects) and offer any databases that Drupal supports..."

After searching from the internet, I found that I need to install pdo_mysql to my server, however I can't get this stuff from the installation package, could anyone suggest the way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be php-pdo
if you are using zypper

```
 zypper install php5-pdo php5-mysql

 or 

 zypper install php-pdo php-mysql
```

Comment: Should I download it from internet or the Suse11 disc will include?

Comment: i think you should be able using zypper, just try zypper install php5-pdo php5-mysql from your command line, if not may be you take alook on cd. or download it like http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.1/repo/oss/suse/x86_64/php5-pdo-5.2.6-49.13.x86_64.rpm if you are using SUSE 11.1 64bit